# git-svn new branch refetches the whole history

Tags: branch, git-svn, history, fetch

I wanted to create a git clone of a big svn repo with git-svn.
My primary problem however is that whenever a new branch is created, the whole history is re-downloaded:
"Found possible branch point" and it starts downloading from r1 ('til 40000...).
How can I (and why do I have to) tell git to skip the commits that were already fetched?

Thanks,
  Lőrinc